# TypeError: Value can't be converted to a dictionary

Tags: javascript

I am getting the following error in Firefox but not in Chrome:

```
TypeError: Value can't be converted to a dictionary
```

The error occurs when clicking on a link defined as

```
<a onclick="scroll()">bla</a>
```

when scroll is defined as a function in my page.

I tried googling it but nothing came up.

The Firefox console is telling me that the error is on the first line of the page. Which is blank. Does anyone have any idea what it can be?

Firefox console is telling me it is on line 0 of my page however there is no javascript there.

Comment: please post the relevant code snippet and any other info relevant

Comment: @rnevius thats not the same error i am getting

Comment: @Nikos M i do not know what code is causing this. i only get this error in firefox and the console is not very helpful

Comment: sure you know at least in what part of whole page code this happens, isolate that part and post it here please, else not easy to help

Comment: probably a type-casting is needed here (e.g `dict(value)`)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is the browser using the built in scroll function which I accidentally overrode.

I changed the name of my function and all works correctly:)

Comment: My case was even more stupid. I called `scrollTo` method this way: `window.scrollTo(0)` and had `TypeError: Value can't be converted to a dictionary.` error on it in FF. In Chrome it was ok, it scrolled to top. Then I realised I should call it `window.scrollTop({top: 0})`.